# Vertically bringing box shadow down

Tags: css

Please take a look at this [test website](http://www.peranscannelljewelers.com.php53-5.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/). I've applied box-shadow around the containers in header and on the main content area. Can somebody tell me if it's possible to bring the shadow a little down on the header so there is no gap in between them? (see the screen shot)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is as close as you can get:

```
box-shadow: 6px 10px 4px -4px #222222, -6px 10px 4px -4px #666666;
```

Just move the header shadows a bit down so they will blend with the content box shadow.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Any idea how I'd apply the shadow on top of the header as well?

Comment: Best would be to have both the header and the content div wrapped inside another div, and add `box-shadow: 0 0 6px #222222` to this one (+ remove it from the others). Possibly you will also need to add margin-top to it, so it doesn't go to the browser top edge but has some gap.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.banner > .container {
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 8px 4px -4px #222 , -6px 8px 4px -4px #666;
box-shadow: 6px 8px 4px -4px #222 , -6px 8px 4px -4px #666;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Any idea how I'd apply the shadow on top of the header as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a container `<div>` to wrap around everything you want with a `box-shadow`, then apply the `box-shadow` only to that `<div>`.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. You should have this anyways. Looks like you got it figured out, though

Comment: Yeah, I agree too. I'll try to take that approach for my future projects.